# pg_search regex search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

Does gem pg_serch supports search by regex, if yes could someone give an example of using regular expressions with pg_search. I could not find it in the documentation. I am looking for something like this

`Model.regex_search(/.*find_string$/)`  is it possible with pg_search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't, nor should it.

`pg_search` utilizes Postgres' full text search extension, so it is already, in a way, doing regex searches on indexed data.

If you want to do a pure regex search against text data in your table, you should use PG's pattern matching.  You can use the operators `~` (case sensitive) and `~*` (case insensitive) within `WHERE` clauses to match against a POSIX regular expression.

```
Model.where("column ~* ?", "regex")
```

If you intend on doing this, I highly recommend that you create indexes on those columns.